# How does interfaces (being a substitute of multiple inheritance) achieve code reuse

Tags: oop, interface, reusability

This is a hard one. I've read this question in forums but nobody could come up with a satisfactory answer.

Coming  from a C++ background, I've been told that Java achieves multiple inheritance through interfaces. One of the main purpose of Inheritance happens to be "code reuse".

I've been trying to understand the use of interfaces through the years. I've not understood whether interfaces achieves code reuse. If yes, then how? 
Please give a **good code example** to substantiate that.

I already understand that interfaces are :

1. used to specify a contract.
2. used to specify additional roles,
   behaviors that the class plays.
3. used to achieve "polymorphism", (eg: A
   method like addKeyListener(KeyListener e) can accept any class that
   implements KeyListener as arguments(so that it becomes of type
   KeyListener),even if its not in the inheritance hierarchy of
   KeyListener.

But how is it useful in the case of code reuse, when I need to add the code for the concrete methods myself....I could as well omit implementing the interface.

So how does Interfaces achieve code reusability (if it does at all)?

Comment: well, I guess the most important part is not the reuse of the interface code (or implementation) but the code that is calling the interface. Since it is the same everywhere you can change the implementation of the interface but reuse the existing code in every module using that interface (not that I say its a good idea to change an interface implementation)

Comment: C++ does not have interfaces?

Answer (score 0):

> Coming from a C++ background, I've been told that Java achieves multiple inheritance through interfaces. One of the main purpose of Inheritance happens to be "code reuse".

Well no, Java just *doesn't* achieve multiple inheritance.  Interfaces are the closest Java can get to multiple inheritance, but it's actually not inheritance, and it doesn't yield code reuse in the same way that inheritance can.

Where it can save you some code is that you can use all the implementations in the same way, rather than having to duplicate calling code.